# SQlite Issue with Nested Queries

Tags: mysql, sql-server, sqlite

Hey guys I have been working on this but I am not able solve it. Can any one help me with this please? I am just confused, can some one help me how to fix the code? Sorry for the content because I could not upload image.

```
SELECT Employee.EmpName, Employee.Age

FROM Employee

WHERE Employee.Age < (SELECT COUNT(Employee.EmployeeID)

FROM Employee, Department

WHERE Department.ManagerID = Employee.EmployeeID 

GROUP BY Employee.EmployeeID

HAVING COUNT(Employee.EmployeeID) >= 2)
```

//(Question) Find the youngest manager who manages more than one department. the query return the name and age of the manager.

SCHEMA

```
Employee(EmployeeID:Integer, EmpName: String, Age: Integer, Salary: Real)
Department(DeptID: Integer, DeptName:String, Budget: Real, ManagerID: Integer)
Works(EmployeeID:Integer, DeptID: Integer, Percent_Time: Integer)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT e2.EmpName, e2.Age
FROM Employee e2 
JOIN Works w2 USING (EmployeeID)
JOIN (SELECT w.DeptID, MIN(e.Age) AS Youngest
      FROM Works w 
      INNER JOIN Employee e USING (EmployeeID)
      GROUP BY w.DeptID) sq
  ON w2.DeptID = sq.DeptID and e2.Age = sq.Youngest
```

Comment: yeah it did work but it didnt return the manager name, it return random EmployeeName